# vertical and horizontal center for image and paragraph

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

How can I align an image with proposition of the paragraph. Please refer sample code in below url.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" class="img-reponsive" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/sikavinraj/d3ymocz7/)

Comment: What is para, what does it mean?

Comment: Please post an actual code that you have tried. And what is para?

Comment: By the way your are obliged to put some code along with the fiddle nice try with the quotation tough -1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" class="img-reponsive pull-left img-thumbnail" />       
    <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever 
since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and 
scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not 
    </div>
</div>
```

Or:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" class="img-reponsive pull-left img-thumbnail" /></div>   
         <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever 
since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and 
scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not 
        industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever 
since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and 
scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not 
       </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" class="img-reponsive" />
          </div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

              <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
              <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

This should work, just put in in table, note that you might adjust your bootstrap tags (col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12)

Answer (score 0):

Really not sure what you mean, but let's try to clean the code a bit and it may be what you are looking for:

- The container should havea `row` class
- The attribute values should be from the small to the big
- Shoudn't you have have a sum of 12 for `col-lg` and `col-md`?
- For `col-xs`, I understand you want the image to be on top.
- I guess that you want the image on the left and the text on the right when the screen is bigger than 750px.
- Also, it is not necessary to add bigger values, it is automatically as the smaller ones, so you don't need `col-lg` if it is like `col-md`.

So here is the clean code, tell me if it what you want:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" class="img-reponsive" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
            has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
            publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
            has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
            publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```